# Is it possible to validate against field converted to symbol?

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

I've got an array of symbols and I would like to use [`validate_inclusion_of`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_inclusion_of) to verify that a field in my model is one of those values in the array. The issue is that the field being compared is a string.

Obviously I could convert the array to store strings or pass a lambda to the `in:` argument which converts the symbols to strings at runtime, but I would rather be able to somehow perform `to_sym` on the field being compared before checking against the array. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You should check out `before_validation` callback.
You can manipulate values before validation perform.